# WebLogic running during a while

Tags: java, sql-server, weblogic, ear

I'm currently working on a WebLOGIC server with an EAR files.

During the deployement, I'm arrived to the status "prepared to install" or "installed".

But when I want to run my project, I received indefinitely the same message like this :

```
09:14:01.747 INFO [com.itnsa.fwk.dao.hibernate.CustomAnnotatedSessionFactoryBean] Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
09:14:03.294 INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalJtaDataSourceConnectionProvider
```

Strange isn't it ?

If you have some informations or if you have received the same error, it will be interesting to speak about it.

KR
Thomas

Comment: What is the connection provider factory that you have mentioned in the hibernate config xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the ear as an application, the right state should be "active" instead of "installed". Are you deploying your ear as a shared library by any chance?

There is no valid deployment state as "Installed." The deployment state is stored in "weblogic.management.runtime.AppRuntimeStateRuntimeMBean." As per the documentation, these are the states:

> STATE_ACTIVE, STATE_ADMIN, STATE_FAILED, STATE_NEW, STATE_PREPARED,
>   STATE_RETIRED,  STATE_UPDATE_PENDING

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/runtime/AppRuntimeStateRuntimeMBean.html

I have seen cases that library installation is stuck on "installed" state. The problem is random and is not reproducible. The "Installed" state can be changed to "Active" by rebooting the domain.